# expiring the session of user if new tab is opened in browser using struts2 interceptors

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2

My application is in struts2.

I have requirement that I am storing my application details in session. I cannot remove those attributes from session. After I log-in I have to choose an object to work on. Now I open a new tab and choose another object for working. Due to which my first object values are over written. Hence if in my first tab I do some work wrong information is updated for that action.

This is how I am planning to solve the issue.

I am trying to set a value in setter method in interceptor class but I cannot access that value in my index.jsp.

This interceptor is called on all the actions and index.jsp is also included in every jsp.

I will maintain a hashtable which will store the userid and a random string of 40 characters. This id will be unique and I will update the userid after comparing the value present in jsp to value stored against the value stored in hastable.

If I find that value matches then I will generate another value and store in jsp and hastable. If value does not matches I will destroy the session.

Kindly advice how can I proceed or is there any other work around to achieve the same.

**code** 
Interceptor class

```
String strFrom = (String)aContext.get(ServletActionContext.ACTION_NAME);
HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)aContext.get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession();

String sessionValue = (String)httpReq.getSession().getAttribute("sessionValue");

String test = httpReq.getParameter("sessionValue");
if(strFrom.equals("ValidateUser")){
        // Do nothing
}else if(sessionValue == null && strFrom.equals("HomePage")){
      session.setAttribute("sessionValue", getRandomString(20));
}else if (sessionValue.equals(session.getAttribute("sessionValue"))){
      session.setAttribute("sessionValue", getRandomString(20));
}else{
            httpReq.setAttribute("message","Session Expired. Please Login Again");
            return "loginAgain";
    }
```

index.jsp

```
<body>
<s:hidden id="hidBidType" value="%{#session.tenderBidType}"/>
<s:property value="%{#session.sessionValue}"/>
<s:hidden name="sessionValue" id="sessionValue" value="%{#session.sessionValue}"/>
</body>
```

login.jsp

```
<form name="loginPage" method="post">
<s:hidden name="sessionValue" id="sessionValue" value="1"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If the session is expired you have to recreate the session object.

Answer (score 0):

For your randomly generated value of 40 characters, why not use timestamp?

Well, I don't see much advantages of your aproach (but I could be wrong, of course). You still can register a SessionListener and check if the user has session, cant't you? So, do you realy need to do all this kind of stuff is up to you, but I wouldn't do it that way - Interceptor for all pages, store value in the page, check if is the same... Just register one SessionListener and put your user ID or some otrher user's unique value in session, compare and destroy session (or whatelse you need).

Hope this helps.

**EDITED**
I'm working on a web application with a similar requirements. What we do (and I'm sure is not the best choice) is after logging open new window without navigation bar and close the loggin window. Then we capture all the events on the window and disable many features like ctrl+tab, right click etc. In this application the user is not allowed to open more than one window. I repeat - this is probably not the best choice. Just an idea.

Comment: I can use timestamp also(Thanks). But my concern is how would I get to know if  new tab is opened and new object is selected to work upon and new object values are not updated in previous object. Here both the objects are under one user only. Session listener will not be able to identify that two different objects as both the objects are under the same user and are opened in same browser but under different tab.

Comment: I have figured out a way to do this but I have a problem that I am not able to fetch the hidden value from index.jsp page to interceptor class. However I am able to fetch the value from hidden field present in login.jsp. I have added the code in my question for reference. Difference is that in my login.jsp hidden field is inside form tag while in index.jsp there is no hidden field.

Comment: You have to send a request to the server to be able to send values. In **index.jsp** - put a form and make submit, or send values by url in anchor. I've made some tests this morning - in a redirect if you don't put an ActionClass you'll not pass trough the interceptor (that was mya case). How do you redirect from index.jsp to the next page?

Comment: I am including index.jsp on every page. If I try to create a form field in it my javascript stops working on many pages. document.forms[0] is being used at many places. So I cannot create form tag in jsp. Moreover in index.jsp if I try to fetch value from after creating a form field and then hidden value, I will get null because the this form is not submitted :(.